# How to output a stem and leaf plot as a plot

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to output a stem and leaf plot to a graphical device, such as `window()` / `quartz()`?  There are at least two ways to get stem and leaf plots in R: [?stem](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/stem.html), in the graphics package, and [?stem.leaf](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/aplpack/docs/stem.leaf), in the aplpack package.  Both output text to the console.  For example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> stem(rbinom(10, size=10, prob=.5))

  The decimal point is at the |

  3 | 0
  4 | 000
  5 | 0
  6 | 00
  7 | 000
```

It would be nice if this could be conveniently output to a graphical device where it could be combined with other plots (say a histogram) in a multi-figure layout, and/or saved as a png file.  I am aware that you can output LaTeX and compile it into a pdf (e.g., see: [Stem and Leaf from R into LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7328354/1217536)), but this isn't very convenient and isn't really what I'm after.  Is there an R function that can do this?  Is there a simple hand-coded solution?

Comment: Take a look at `package:ascii`

Comment: The pdf documentation on CRAN is pretty sparse, @BondedDust. Are you thinking of `fig()` to capture output & save it as png? Could it, or another function, output to a standard graphics window?

Comment: Well, not really. I was thinking you would need to send the results of `capture.output(<your expression>)` to some mark(up/down) facility. I agree it's kind of painful to try to do any ascii-printing to the default plot device. I can do it, but only with pain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one simple example:

```
plot.new()
tmp <- capture.output(stem(iris$Petal.Length))
text( 0,1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj=c(0,1), family='mono' )
```

[image]

If you want to overlay a histogram then you probably want to use the `text` function on each of the elements of `tmp` rather than `paste`ing.  Functions like `strheight` and `strwidth` will be useful to find the coordinates.

There are also functions in the gplots and plotrix packages for plotting text and adding tables to plots (other functions in other packages probably exist along these lines as well).

Comment: This just gave me a flashback to my C programming course.

Comment: This was essentially what I was calling the "painful" approach. I think you also described (a few years ago) a facility to send to gnuplot.

Comment: @BondedDust, I don't think the above is too painful.  Trying to line everything up with a histogram would start being uncomfortable, but I wouldn't consider it painful.

Comment: My comment was too negative. I did upvote both your answer and the question as useful.

Comment: That's great, Greg.  Thanks a lot.  I also incorporated it into a function `stem.plot <- function(x){ ... }` and it works great.

Answer (score 4):

Following is equivalent:

```
set.seed(1)
xx = rbinom(10, size=10, prob=.5)
barplot(t(table(xx)), horiz=T)
```

[image]

For even more similar:

```
set.seed(1)
xx = rnorm(10)

xxch = as.character(xx)
ff = sapply(strsplit(xxch, '\\.'), function(x) x[1])
ss = sapply(strsplit(xxch, '\\.'), function(x) x[2])
first = sapply(strsplit(ss, ''), function(x) x[1])
second = sapply(strsplit(ss, ''), function(x) x[2])
third = sapply(strsplit(ss, ''), function(x) x[3])
dd = data.frame(ff, first, second, third)
dd = cbind(dd[1], sapply(dd[-1], as.numeric))
ddt = data.table(dd)
gg = ddt[order(ff,first)][,paste(first, collapse=""),by=ff]
gg$rr = rownames(gg)
ggplot(gg)+geom_text(aes(x=rr, y=1, label=paste(ff,'|',V1))) +
theme(axis.text = element_blank(),axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
coord_flip()+ labs(title="Decimal is at |")
```

[image]

The code may need to be tweaked for different sets.

Using capture.output (as suggested by @Greg) and plotting with ggplot:

```
tmp <- capture.output(stem(iris$Petal.Length))
stemdf = data.frame(tmp, rr=1:length(tmp))
ggplot(stemdf)+ geom_text(aes(x=rr, y=0, label=tmp), hjust=0) + 
    coord_flip()+ theme_classic() + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)+ 
    scale_y_discrete(breaks=NULL, limits=c(0,1))+ 
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        panel.grid=element_blank(), 
        axis.line=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think this is only equivalent because the output from my example is integers. Consider the output from this case: `set.seed(1); stem(rnorm(10))`.

Comment: Please see addition to my answer above.

Comment: I think @GregSnow's code may be easier for me to work with, but I appreciate the effort you went through to help.

Comment: ggplot can also be used to plot the captured text (added to my answer above). More options for tweaking may be available here.

Comment: @mso, would you know how to fix the alignment of the ``|`` when the lhs combines single digits with double digits, etc.? (in ``ggplot2``) Thanks.