# Stem-and-leaf display graphical output with subset highlight in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to highlight the subset of the given set on graphic output of stem-and-leaf display in R, viz:

```
library(fmsb)
xs <- c(rep(10,3), rep(20, 2), rep(30, 5))
gstem(xs)

xs_to_highlight <- c(10, 30)
```

The highlight of 10 and 30 can be in colour, underline etc. No strict requirements.

Comment: No strict requirement, eh? How about we give you a requirement...tell us the nature of your console or the output target.

Comment: Basically there is really no requirement how to highlight indicated numbers. I am not interested in console output but in graph window output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a back to back stem and leaf plot, with the X's to be highlighted on one side, and the rest on the other side.  The [?stem.leaf.backback](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/aplpack/docs/stem.leaf) function in the aplpack package can do this for you.  All you really need to do is write some code to extract the highlighted values from the rest.  Consider:

```
library(aplpack)
xs              <- c(rep(10,3), rep(20, 2), rep(30, 5))
xs_to_highlight <- c(10, 30)
other_xs        <- xs[-match(xs_to_highlight, xs)]
stem.leaf.backback(x=xs_to_highlight, y=other_xs, m=1)
# ____________________________
#   1 | 2: represents 12, leaf unit: 1 
# xs_to_highlight
#                 other_xs
# ____________________________
#   1       0| 1 |00     2   
#            | 2 |00    (2)  
#   1       0| 3 |0000   4   
# ____________________________
# n:        2     8      
# ____________________________
```

Comment: Hi gung, is there any way to print it into graphic output?

Comment: @Artem, you may want to check out the question I asked here: [How to output a stem and leaf plot as a plot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26532564/1217536).