# how to add stem-leaf plot in R subplot

Tags: r, plot

I want to have four subplot in one figure

one of them is a stem-leaf plot

My code like this :

```
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(df, main="Histogram of df",breaks=10, xlab="birth weight (oz)", col="orange")
hist(df, main="Histogram of wt",prob = TRUE,breaks=50,xlab="birth weight (oz)", col="green")
boxplot(df, main="Boxplot",col = "yellow")
stem(data)
```

And this gives me the following error

"The following object is masked from package"

and the stem plot does not show in my figure it is empty in the last subplot

THANKS for your help

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532564/how-to-output-a-stem-and-leaf-plot-as-a-plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variables of `df` (assuming it is a data frame) you want to plot using (for instance) the `$` sign. Furthermore, `stem` gives a text as output. You have to convert it to a plot using `text()` function (see [How to output a stem and leaf plot as a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532564/how-to-output-a-stem-and-leaf-plot-as-a-plot)).

Here is an example using `mtcars` dataset:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
hist(mtcars$cyl, col="orange")
hist(mtcars$mpg, col="green")
boxplot(mtcars$hp, main="Boxplot",col = "yellow")
plot.new()
tmp <- capture.output(stem(mtcars$drat))
text(0, 1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj=c(0,1), family='mono', cex=1) #you can adjust the size of the text using cex parameter
```

[image]