# How do i add a title to my stem leaf diagram in basic R?

Tags: r

I would like to add a title to my stem leaf diagram in basic R but how? Im am using the Palmerpenguins package and library palmerpenguins. I already tried main= "" but it doesnt work?

```
stem (flipper_length_mm, scale = 1)
```

Comment: You can out out the results of stem to a plot window: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532564/how-to-output-a-stem-and-leaf-plot-as-a-plot . Then just an a `title("your title")`

Comment: I really don't understand. I am a beginner in R.

Comment: `stem` outputs the plot in the terminal. And so you can't really add a title to it. One way around this is to send the output from `stem` to an actual plot window, as done in the link. You can then add a title. (So using the code form the link use `plot.new(); tmp <- capture.output(stem(iris$Petal.Length)) ; text( 0,1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj=c(0,1), family='mono' ) ; title("your title")`)